# Background calling while in app

Tags: iphone, android, background, cordova

What I actually want is calling a phone number from a button in my app (I know that this part is do-able). But once the call is accepted I want to go back to my app to be able to make notes.

So I would prefer to do all that without leaving my app.

How would that be possible?

And is it possible with iOS, Android or through Phonegap?

Comment: Not possible with iOS standard resources. Don't know about Android, though my guess is probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is possible in **Android** because **Android** allows the to run Background process through **Android Service** . When you accept call and can always go back and do anything you want in Android.  No idea about **iPhone**. AFAIK not possible **iPhone** not allows background process to run.